# Mapping private network ports for Terraform ingress/egress using to_port and from_port configs?

Tags: terraform

I'm unsure on the Terraform port forwarding nomenclature here. If I have an application on port 5000 inside a private network that I'd like to expose to the public on port 8000 - which variables do I set?

Would it be from the perspective of the private network?

```
from_port: 5000
to_port: 8000
```

Or the perspective of public network?

```
from_port: 8000
to_port: 5000
```

Would I also need to set egress values if my internal application needs to respond with data?

Example from: [intro to terraform](https://blog.gruntwork.io/an-introduction-to-terraform-f17df9c6d180)

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elb" {
  name = "terraform-example-elb"
  # Allow all outbound
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  # Inbound HTTP from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have complete example? ingress/egress rules of what? AWS security groups?

Comment: Hello - I added an example into my original queston. It's from the popular blog article "An introduction to terraform" which is where my question originated. Since the example uses the same port number for both from_port and to_port - I can't understand which port is which[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about a security group (SG) as a closed **bubble** around your instance. It has nothing to do with what's happening inside your instance. It operates outside of an instance.

The SG rules you set, **make holes in this bubble**, specifying what traffic (TCP, UDP) on what ports is allowed into the instance and outside the instance.

In your case, since you want to allow incoming traffic on port `8000` to your instance, you would make a "hole" with port `8000`:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elb" {
  name = "terraform-example-elb"
  # Allow all outbound
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  # Inbound port 8000 from anywhere
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8000
    to_port     = 8000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

The above SG will allow incoming traffic on port 8000 to your instance. No other port is allowed, thus `from_port == to_port`. What your instance is doing once this traffic is allowed, it is outside of SG scope and rules. So generally you would have to have a server on the instance listening on port 8000. If your application works on port 5000, then you need **reverse proxy** such as nginx on the instance. Nginx would accept connections on port 8000 and **redirect** them to your app on port 5000::

```
client--->SG:8000--->Instance:8000--->Nginx:8000--->Your app:5000
```

In contrast, if you write that

```
from_port: 5000
to_port: 8000
```

you would open **all ports** from 5000 to 8000 to go through the bubble and reach your instance.

Comment: oh wow okay - didn't know that `from_port` `to_port` specified a range! This cleared it up for me thank you.

Comment: @alex No problem. Glad I could help.